# pd.read_csv with some missing columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a txt file as below and I want to read in this file as df, but got an error: **Too many columns specified**, because row 3 and row 4 only have 3 columns, is it possible to **keep all my 5 columns** and just let the missing columns in row 3 and 4 empty?

```
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep =";", dtype = str, headers = None)

1;2;3;4;5
1;2;3;4;5
1;2;3
1;2;3
```

ideal df:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
 1    2    3    4     5
 1    2    3    4     5
 1    2    3
 1    2    3
```

Comment: maybe something like this. 1;2;3;null;null. Normally you dont work with tables like this. Why are they missing or not excisting?

Comment: You should change the argument  `headers` to  `header`.

Answer (score 1):

Works just fine for me. My pandas version == 1.2.1

This is the command I used:

```
pd.read_csv(data, sep =";", header=None)
```

the output:

```
   0  1  2    3    4
0  1  2  3  4.0  5.0
1  1  2  3  4.0  5.0
2  1  2  3  NaN  NaN
3  1  2  3  NaN  NaN
```

You change the names of columns with `names` parameter in your `read_csv` function